# Using psuedo elements for the style of an ordered list, while preserving indentation

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where the CMS is generating a list of the form

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Here's list item 1, which will wrap onto the next next due to the size of the ul element containing it</a>  
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Here's list item 2, which will wrap onto the next next due to the size of the ul element containing it</a>          
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Here's list item 3, which will wrap onto the next next due to the size of the ul element containing it</a>          
    </li>
</ul>
```

and I need the client wants the list style to be `'>'` characters and be a different color than the text. So I decided to use the classic pseudo-element hack, but now the problem is that I want the text to be aligned when it wraps to the next line, as in normal lists. I've tried seemingly every combination of padding/text-indent/margin over the `li` and `li:before` elements, but can't get it right.

Here's a fiddle of the scenario:

http://jsfiddle.net/t0wxsf0j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you give your pseudo element a negative margin:

```
ul > li:before {content: ">";margin-left:-.8em;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t0wxsf0j/1/